# Сборка проекта

Tags: c#, развертывание

Доброго времени суток, не знаю, правильно ли я назвал вопрос, но суть такова:
Есть WPF проект, заходу в папку с проектом, там есть папки: **bin**, **obj**, **Properties**, **Resourses** и все мои исходники. В папке bin есть папка **Debug**, там есть exe к моей программе.

Как мне в кучу собрать весь этот проект? Я имею ввиду, собрать все нужные для работы файлы в одну папку. Какие файлы нужные, какие нет?(звучит глупо,но иначе не знаю как сформулировать).

Comment: Все файлы лежат в bin/Release. (Только не забудьте откомпилировать target = Release)

Comment: @alex91, может вам лучше подумать о создании установщика? Тогда голова не будет болеть о том, какие файлы нужны/не нужны. В Visual Studio установщик легко генерируется.

Comment: target = Release - Это нужно в assembly файле указать?

Comment: это в "Пакетном построении" лучше указать и откомпилировать.

Answer (score 4):

Офигенная статья в самом MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2444w33.aspx
В подробностях расписано, какие виды инсталлеров можно сделать, и в чем их отличия друг от друга.
Если в общем, то есть 2 пути:

- ClickOnce Application
- Windows MSI Installer

Первый - очень классный, легкий, быстрый установщик, да ещё и с автообновлялкой приложения при выходе новой версии.

Второй - позволяет гораздо больше всегда впихивать в установочный проект, да ещё и имеет более широкие возможности настройки.

На опыте развертывания в организации могу сказать, что использую ClickOnce, так как для небольших проектов оно подходит очень классно (кстати, GitHub и Google Chrome тоже его используют).

Comment: Кстати, а Nant является аналогом того чтот Вы перечислили?

Comment: Да, Nant делает тоже самое. Тем, кто переходит с Java на C# - самое оно :)

Comment: Тогда это для меня:)

Answer (score 2):

Обычно всё нужное лежит в папке /bin/{конфигурация(обычно Debug | Release)}

Но тут надо понимать, что туда могут не попадать dll которые установлены на девелоперской машине, поэтому, очень простой путь предложил [@olter](/users/5357/olter) - создайте визардом installer - он для простых проектов сам сможет разобраться что надо а что нет.